# VS code support for multi-root Azure Function projects under a common git repository

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have a git repository with a couple of files at the root level, including a `README.md` and a `.gitignore` file. There are 4 subprojects, each in its own subdirectory of the repository root:

```
  (root)
  .gitignore
  README.md
  Subproject1/
    ...
  Subproject2/
    ...
  Subproject3/
    ...
  Subproject4/
    ...
```

Two of these subprojects are Azure Functions projects whose functions get deployed to different Azure Function applications.

When I open the root folder, I get notified that multiple Azure functions projects were found and that I should either pick 1 as the default or set up a multi-root project, as described at [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/wiki/Multiple-function-projects).

I can do this to set up a multi-root project with each of the 4 subfolders, but now the files in the root folder (`README.md` and `.gitignore`) are no longer visible in the project. I was hoping to just add the few files I want to access the workspace, but according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45177) that isn't possible.

Of course I could move the top-leve files to somewhere completely separate and add that folder to the workspace, but this takes the files outside of the git repository where all of these code artifacts need to be committed.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to arrange things where a single git repository has multiple subprojects from the common root folder, separable within VS code to allow things like multiple Azure Functions projects to work?